# Обработка файла медленнее, чем его прочтение с диска

Tags: файлы, golang, файловая-система

Привет

Пишу на го токенизатор. Читаю файл. После его прочтения, разбиваю на токены. Проблема в том, что чтение с диска происходит в 1.5 раза быстрее, чем обработка файла. Это крайне странно, учитывая то, что токенизация подразумевает под собой перебор символов в считанной строке и не более. Т.е. программа отрабатывает за линию.

Чего я не вижу?

```
/*
    Разделение строки на токены. Токенами считаются непрерывные (без посторонних символов) слова на русском и английском языках и числа

    Входные параметры:
    data string -- строка, подлежащая разделению
    listTokens *[]string -- указатель на список токенов
 */
func (self *STokeneizer) split(data *string, arrayTokens *[]string) {
    // Рассматриваемый токен
    token := ""
    // Текущий символ
    symbolCurrent := rune(0)
    // Предыдущий символ
    symbolPrev := rune(0)



    for key, value := range *data {
        symbolCurrent = unicode.ToLower(value)
        if key == 0 {
            // Отдельно рассматриваем случай для первого символа входной строки
            if self.isNumeric(symbolCurrent) ||
                self.isSymbol(symbolCurrent) {
                // Если первый символ относится к какому-нибудь токену, то берём его в рассмотрение
                token += string(symbolCurrent)
            }
        } else {
            if self.isNumeric(symbolCurrent) && self.isNumeric(symbolPrev) ||
                self.isSymbol(symbolCurrent) && self.isSymbol(symbolPrev) {
                // Если предыдущий символ -- цифра или буква, текущий символ -- цифра или буква, то
                // продолжаем формировать токен
                token += string(symbolCurrent)
            } else if self.isNumeric(symbolCurrent) && !self.isNumeric(symbolPrev) ||
                self.isSymbol(symbolCurrent) && !self.isSymbol(symbolPrev) {
                // Как только токен заканчивается -- это означает, что встретился символ-разделитель.
                // Так будет до тех пор, пока не встретится новый токен. В таком случае данное условие
                // окажется истиным. Предыдущий токен (если он не пустой) добавится к общему списку
                // токенов. Будет сформирован новый токен из symbolCurrent
                if len(token) != 0 {
                    *arrayTokens = append(*arrayTokens, []string{token}...)
                }
                token = string(symbolCurrent)
            }
        }

        // Текущий символ становится предыдущим
        symbolPrev = symbolCurrent
    }

    return
}
```

Статистика по распаршенным файлам:

```
0.6666444607287989
0.5618823162166381
0.5713877865646502
0.5713551628650547
0.5000250037505626
0.5976016788248226
0.3333333333333333
0.39999600283798503
0.499975018735948
0.4923654691900973
0.46150534658641024
0.5456544055524769
0.4571920146380097
0.5035755363304496
0.47998848833444585
0.46434996145170043
0.5999640165523858
0.4375394262658564
0.49996752224726065
0.44201533551990074
0.5380860501049298
0.4002159762426133  
NaN
1.0000999300489657
0.5999300524606546
0.5612949550449551
0.9990007993605116
0.3332889258950874
0.9996002798041371
0.5
0.3332667133006895
0.24987509992006396
0 
0 
0
0.3329606782322839 
NaN
0.6665778517901748
0.3997501748775857
1.000399720195863
0.6248797851745457
0.5714204139900071
0.9995504270942605
0.4284939329050678
```

Каждая отдельная строка задаёт метрику:

Время прочтения файла по отношению ко времени токенизации.

Comment: Классические вопросы: как вы определяли время? Пробовали ли вы профилировать код для нахождения горячих точек?

Comment: Профайлер под го только консольный. С винды это делать крайне неудобно. Завтра попробую на работе это сделать.

Comment: Время замерял таймером

Comment: Файл мог быть подтянут целиком из кэша (вы же ведь не первый один раз по нему прошлись до замера, верно?), поэтому без конкретных цифр и кода замера времени говорить что-то однозначно будет очень сложно.

Comment: Файл не мог быть подтянут целиком из кэша, так как его размер очень большой 17 GB. Читается он итеративно: по одному документу. Для большего понимания: файл представляет собой русскую википедию. Читается он подокументно при помощи github.com/dustin/go-wikiparse. Каждый документ разбивается на токены.

Comment: Как минимум вот это `token += string(symbolCurrent)` не очень хорошо, потому что конкатенация строк каждый раз создаёт новую строку, что нагружает сборщик мусора. Использйте буфер в `[]byte`. И ещё не понятно, почему у вас аргументы - указатели.

Comment: @Ainar-G Уже написал про свойство конкатенации, создавать каждый раз новую строку и при таком подходе я думаю это максимум что можно сделать именно с функцией, есть вариант запускать функцию в несколько потоков.

Comment: Да, про несколько потоков я думал. Но это позже запилю. А строки в go константные, я правильно понимаю, да? Что насчёт []byte? Но что-то мне подсказывает, что сильнее заоптимайзить этот кусок кода не получится. Хотя, можно попробовать какое-нибудь дерево построить. Типо суффиксного.

Comment: []byte не будет создавать новую строку каждый раз при добавлении.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно проблема связана с постоянными аллокациями памяти.

У вас есть переменная token типа string. string в golang - неизменяемый тип. Т.е. каждый раз, когда вы делаете

```
token += string(symbolCurrent)
```

у вас происходит выделение нового кусочка памяти и копирования строки туда. Дополнительно сборщику добавляется задача по проходу и освобождению прежнего куска памяти.

Такое копирование у вас происходит на каждый символ из 17Гбайтного файла. Я думаю что проблема тормозов может быть как раз в этом.

Попробуйте вместо token string использовать что-то вроде token := make([]byte, 0, 128) и потом добавлять байты к нему байты.

Когда обработка очередного токена закончилась - делать

```
*arrayTokens = append(*arrayTokens, []string{string(token)})
token = token[0:0]
```

т.е. преобразовывать в строку 1 раз - одним копированием и потом для token не выделять память еще раз, а переиспользовать уже имеющийся буфер.